# Printing a smile face :)

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I'm supposed to print a smile face with Ascii txt using an inputted 2D array of int values. So far my code changes the int to Ascii and then prints, however it only prints 2 lines.

I'm sure this is a misunderstanding of the code on my part but I'm not sure how to fix it.

My code:

```
def display(x):
    for i in x:
        for j in i:
            j = chr(j)
            print (j, end = ' ')
```

Comment: For debugging, what happens when you have your code `print(len(i))` and `print(len(x))` on every iteration of your inner and outer loop?

Comment: Please use the tag for the specific python version you're using.

Comment: when I used either of the x(len(x)) it would print the smiley face, but with a 9 at the end.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  This means an example 2d input array, the expected output, and the actual output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this

```
def display(x):
    for i in x:
        for j in i:
            j = chr(j)
            print (j, end = ' ')
        print()
```

if each `i` represent a line, you need add a extra print to start over in the next line

Comment: This makes so much sense. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 3):

A '2d array' is presumably a sequence of sequences, with each inner sequence presenting a line.  Therefore, you need to add a newline after each line.  You your code emits no newlines, I suspect you only see 2 lines because your display added a soft linebreak at some point.

I think you just need to add a `print()` line at the end.

```
            ...
            print (j, end = ' ')
        print()
```

Here is equivalent code that works with an example face.

```
# Create ints for known face
orig = '''\
_____
| O |
| - |
-----
'''

ints = [[ord(c) for c in line] for line in orig.splitlines()]
for line in ints: print(line)

# Reproduce orig

copy = '\n'.join(((''.join(chr(i) for i in line)) for line in ints))
print(copy)
```

prints

```
[95, 95, 95, 95, 95]
[124, 32, 79, 32, 124]
[124, 32, 45, 32, 124]
[45, 45, 45, 45, 45]
_____
| O |
| - |
-----
```

Comment: I like how you made a universe out of an atom.... Forget the mountain and mole hill example it just didn't do your posts justice.Thanks for the...... help?

Answer (score -4):

You need to be using python 3.x to use `end=''`. In Python 2.x you would just end your line with a comma.

```
print j,
```

Comment: I am using python 3.x

Comment: you can also use that in py2 with the corresponding future import

Comment: FWIW, the print function is available in Python 2.6+, you just need to use `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the script before other imports.